# Maximal orders and surface subgroups of even genus

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, surfaces, fuchsian-groups, quaternion-algebras

Let $A$ be a quaternion algebra over a totally real number field $k$. Suppose that $A$ splits at exactly one real place of $A$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a maximal order in $A$. Then $\mathcal{O}$ contains finite-index surface subgroups.

Let $S$ be the orbifold obtained as the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by $\mathcal{O}$. If $\chi(S)$ is an integer congruent to $0$ modulo $4$ then all its surface subgroups will be of odd genus. It appears that there are infinitely many such $A$ with $\chi(S)\equiv 0\mod 4$.

Is there infinitely many $A$ that admits a maximal orders $\mathcal{O}$ that contains a surface subgroup of even genus?